# Normalizing Eigenvectors (Length equal to 1)

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am a bit confused as I have seen texts that normalize the vectors to get unique solutions and others that do not. Is there an empirical rule about when we should set the length of the vector equal to 1 and when not? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes it just makes the vectors easier to deal with.  If that is the case, or you're dealing with basis vectors and the like, it's common to normalize the vector.  Otherwise, it is up to the good judgement of whoever is writing the text as to whether or not to normalize the vector, though I think most of the time he or she would not.

Comment: Ah ok, so it really depends on the situation and there's no general rule. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Even if you normalise your vector, you still get two solutions, say $u$ and $-u$ ( where $u$ has length one). There are situations where unit vectors are required (eg to apply theorems that require particular vectors to be unit length- an example is orthogonal diagonalisation of a matrix), and situations where it does not matter.